# CPLEX SheetWrite error: Sheet data not supported on this platform

Tags: excel, cplex

I have this CPLEX model, the decision variables are intervals. I am able to read data from an excel file and I have no problem in writing float/integer results to excel. However error message "Sheet data not supported on this platform" shows when I try to write interval decision variables to the same excel.

The variables I like to save look like this
[variable to save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNcQR.jpg)

Since I need to make a gantt chart using the results (with vba code), I prefer not to save the results in other formats and I need to save all the information from this table. Anyone can help me to solve this? Or if any suggestions on other methods of making a gantt chart from the results, that also helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for "Sheet data not supported on this platform", you could see [Read without SheetRead (useful for MacOs and Linux)](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/readwithoutsheetread.mod) in [OPL and Excel](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/excel-rocket-science-optimization-alex-fleischer/)

```
// Read from an Excel spreadsheet without SheetRead
// which means you can use this on non Windows platform

execute
    {

    function read_excel(filename,sheetname,skiprows,nrows,cols,datfilename,resname)
    {
        var quote="\"";
        
        var python=new IloOplOutputFile("c:\\temp\\readexcel.py");
        
        python.writeln("import pandas as pd");
        python.writeln("import xlrd");
        python.writeln("df=pd.read_excel('"+filename+"'"+",sheet_name = '"+sheetname+"'"+
        ",skiprows = "+skiprows+  ",nrows= "+nrows+ ","
        +"header=None,usecols = '"+cols+"')");
        python.writeln("print(df)");
        
        
        
        python.writeln("res = open(",quote,datfilename,quote,",",quote,"w",quote,")");
        python.writeln("res.write(",quote,resname,"=[",quote,")");
        python.writeln("res.write(",quote,"\\","n",quote,")");
        python.writeln("for i, row in enumerate(df.values):");
       
        python.writeln("   res.write(",quote,"[",quote,")");
        
        python.writeln("   for j in row:");
       
        python.writeln("      if (j==j):");
        python.writeln("         res.write(str(j))");
        python.writeln("         res.write(\",\")");
       
        python.writeln("   res.write(\"],\")    ");
        python.writeln("   res.write(",quote,"\\","n",quote,")");
        python.writeln("res.write(\"];\")");
        python.writeln("res.close()");
        python.close();
       
        python.close();
        
        IloOplExec("C:\\Python36\\python.exe c:\\temp\\readexcel.py",true);
        
    }
    read_excel("c:\\\\temp\\\\read2Darray.xls","Sheet1",0,2,"B:D","c:\\\\temp\\\\resexcel","res");
}
```

and for exporting intervals you could first turn the intervals into tuple sets and then export tuple sets.

For instance with the zoo scheduling example:

```
/*

Model written by Philippe Laborie

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/zoo-buses-kids-optimization-resource-allocation-philippe-laborie/

*/
using CP;

tuple Bus { string Name; int Seats; int Cost; int Avail; int Outward; int Return; }

{Bus} Buses = {
  < "A40", 40,  500,  480, 30, 25 >,
  < "B40", 40,  500,  480, 30, 25 >,
  < "C40", 40,  500,  480, 30, 25 >,
  < "D40", 40,  500,  480, 30, 25 >,
  < "E40", 40,  500,  510, 30, 25 >,
  < "F30", 30,  400,  480, 25, 20 >,
  < "G30", 30,  400,  480, 25, 20 >,
  < "H30", 30,  400,  480, 25, 20 >,
  < "I30", 30,  400,  480, 25, 20 >,
  < "J30", 30,  400,  510, 25, 20 >
};

int Opening    = 600; // 10:00
int NbKids     = 300;
int NbTeachers = 3;
int NbMaxTrips = 2;

dvar interval outwardTrip[b in Buses][i in 1..NbMaxTrips] optional in b.Avail..Opening size b.Outward;
dvar interval roundTrip  [b in Buses][i in 1..NbMaxTrips] optional size b.Outward+b.Return;

minimize sum(b in Buses, i in 1..NbMaxTrips) (presenceOf(outwardTrip[b][i]) * b.Cost);
subject to {
  sum(b in Buses, i in 1..NbMaxTrips) (presenceOf(outwardTrip[b][i]) * b.Seats) >= NbKids;
  sum(b in Buses, i in 1..NbMaxTrips) pulse(roundTrip[b][i],1) <= NbTeachers; 
  forall(b in Buses) {
    forall(i in 1..NbMaxTrips) {
      presenceOf(outwardTrip[b][i]) == presenceOf(roundTrip[b][i]);startAtStart(outwardTrip[b][i], roundTrip[b][i]);
      if (i>1) {
        presenceOf(roundTrip[b][i]) => presenceOf(roundTrip[b][i-1]);
        endBeforeStart(roundTrip[b][i-1], roundTrip[b][i]);
      }
    }
  }
}

tuple result
{
  string name;
  int seats;
  int s;
  int e;
}

{result} results=
{<b.Name,b.Seats,startOf(outwardTrip[b][i]),endOf(outwardTrip[b][i])> | b in Buses, i in 1..NbMaxTrips : presenceOf(outwardTrip[b][i])==1};
  
execute
{
  writeln(results);
}
```